# MonoGame 3.6 install script not detecting MonoDevelop 6 / Can't create MonoGame app within MonoDevelop

Tags: monodevelop

Dual-pronged problem that might be caused by the same thing!

So, I'm trying to install monogame/monodevelop.

Installed MonoDevelop with `sudo apt-get install mono-devel`. That opens appropriately and seems to work fine otherwise. Got a basic C# Console 'Hello, world!' to run correctly.

I went [here](http://www.monogame.net/2017/03/01/monogame-3-6/) and downloaded the version for Linux. I gave it executable permission with `chmod +x monogame-sdk.run` and ran it. It produced the following:

```
$ sudo ./monogame-sdk.run 
Verifying archive integrity... All good.
Uncompressing Monogame Pipeline 
Installer.......................................................... 
..........................
Dependencies:
- mono-runtime...................................[Found]
- gtk-sharp3.....................................[Found]

Optional Dependencies:
- MonoDevelop 6..................................[Not Found]
- Rider..........................................[Not Found]
- referenceassemblies-pcl / mono-pcl.............[Found]
- ttf-mscorefonts-installer / mscore-fonts.......[Found]

Continue (Y, n): y
Previous version detected, trying to uninstall...
Installing MonoGame SDK...
Installing MonoDevelop Addin...
bash: ?????: command not found
Creating launcher items...
./postinstall.sh: line 142: gtk-update-icon-cache: command not found
Adding mimetype...
To uninstall MonoGame SDK you can run "monogame-uninstall" from terminal.
```

Pretty much looks like the installation did not finish correctly, but I'm not sure what's wrong with the script to make it do that. As a probable result of this, MonoDevelop doesn't allow me to create a MonoGame app of any kind. ([this](http://www.monogame.net/documentation/?page=creating_a_new_project_md) doesn't appear when I try to create a new solution)

If there's any other information you might need, please let me know!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Which version of MonoDevelop do you have installed? I was on version 5.10 and upgraded to version 6.x which solved my problem.